# Two divs is going through eachother when resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is when i resize the window(smaller) One of my divs just go through and on top of my navigation bar... Which is annoying, but i believe there is a easy way to fix it. I can give you the code, but should test it in your **editor program** - and then resize, youll see what i mean.

HTML CODE HERE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="WorkFieldStartpage.css"/>


</head>
<body>
<div id="upperblock">


</div>

<div class="topbar"></div>  



   <div id="pageContainer">

       <div id="pageContainer2">


                <div>
                    <div id="leftnavigation">
                        <ul>
                        <li> <h4> Navigation </h4> </li>    
                        <li>Test text</li>
                        <li>Test text</li>
                        <li>Test text</li>

                        </ul>


                        </div>
                    <div id="mainContainer">

                        <div id="newsfeed"></div>



                    </div>

                </div>
        </div>
    </div>     

   </body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
color: #333;
line-height: 1.28;
text-align: left;
direction: ltr;

}

div {
display: block;   



}



.topbar {
 font-family: sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #11BD83;
height: px;
width: 100%;
position:fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;

}


#pageContainer {
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
zoom: 1;
min-height: 600px;
}

#pageContainer2 {
margin: 0;
outline: none;
padding: 0;
width: auto;



}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

h4 {
text-decoration:underline;



}





#mainContainer {
display: block;
width: 620px;    
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
min-height: 800px;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
margin-top: 58px;   
}

 #leftnavigation {
 float: left;
 height: 300px;
 width: 120.5px;
 text-align: left;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 display:block;




}



  #newsfeed {




  }
```

Answer (score 0):

make #leftnavigation AND #mainContainer div `float:left`

Comment: That messes the whole thing completely up

Answer (score 0):

Set to the `maincontainer` div an `overflow:auto;` property. This will disable to overlap on floated elements.

Comment: Hey, and thanks. It works kinda good, only bad thing is, when it hits my navbar now, it pushes it upwards, which it shouldn't. It should just not be able to get in its place. Any way how to fix that?

Comment: Try go look at facebook. (And dont get me wrong, im not trying to make a social network.) Then at the startpage, try resize the window. Nothing really messes anything up, the window just gets smaller. Thats how i want it